# Is it possible to pass existing methods to callbacks defined similar to UIView.animateWithDuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, uiviewanimation

The method accepts up to two callbacks, `animations` and `complete`. If I define what needs to be done in class methods, how to pass them to `animateWithDuration`?

From:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:

the signature looks like

`+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations`

Usually it looks something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     _someView.frame = CGRectMake(-150, -200, 460, 650);
                     _someView.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
```

So what I am looking for is assigning `animations` to some method in my class.

This method is chosen as an well-known example. However the root is that I have my own class that tries to do the same approach and I was wondering if I could keep code cleaner by not calling class methods within callbacks.

The biggest thing that I don't like is `NSError **` parameter I am using for my callback that is called in case of errors. Subcalls will require some sort of global variable and I really don't like that. So here is my signature for completeness:

```
- (void)registerWithEmail:(NSString *)email
                     name:(NSString *)name
             willRegister:(void (^)(void))willRegister
              didRegister:(void (^)(void))didRegister
            registerError:(void (^)(NSError**))registerError;
```

Comment: On a side note, you should have a BOOL return type when you use an error parameter like this. Callers of the method check the return value for success/fail to decide if they should read the registerError variable. See the NSError programming guide... might be a compiler warning now i think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the method from within the block.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^{
                     [self yourMethod];
                     //...or
                     [YourClass yourMethod]; // as you said 'class' methods 
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self yourCompletion];
                 }];
```

Comment: +1. Yes, I can do that. I took this method as an example. I have my own class that is based on such callbacks and I was wondering if I could avoid such subcalls.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: The signatures have several parameters and it just looks rather unappealing. The biggest problem is `NSError ** parameter`, i.e. ability to return an error to a callback. I will have to create some class global variable for that instead of having it local to a method. I will add that to the question.

Comment: How are these parameters going to be filled? I still don't understand.  The signature of what is ugly? Your methods, or animateWithDuration? Maybe in your question write some example code of what you would like it to look like.

Comment: Just updated the question. Please see my signature in the question body.

Comment: Aesthetically pleasing or not, this is pretty normal pattern in Objective-C, and you shouldn't have to create a global for the error handler.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think you are right for this particular use case. I have switched to protocol/delegate based model.

Answer (score 1):

I also think your signature is wrong, and you are mixing up indirect references to NSError objects with blocks. It should be:

```
- (void) registerWithEmail:(NSString *)email
                 name:(NSString *)name
         willRegister:(void (^)(void))willRegister
          didRegister:(void (^)(void))didRegister
        registerError:(void (^)(NSError*))registerError;
```

...and you would call it like so:

```
[self registerWithEmail:@"email@email.com" name:@"dave" willRegister:^{
    //.. will register
} didRegister:^{
    //.. did register
} registerError:^(NSError *error) {
    // do somethign with the error
}];
```

---

If you wanted to use the indirect reference to the NSError variable, your signature might look something more like:

```
- (BOOL)registerWithEmail:(NSString *)email
                 name:(NSString *)name
         willRegister:(void (^)(void))willRegister
          didRegister:(void (^)(void))didRegister
        registerError:(NSError**)registerError;
```

..and you would call this like so:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL result = [self registerWithEmail:@"email@email.com" name:@"dave" willRegister:^{
    //.. will register
} didRegister:^{
    //.. did register
} registerError:&error];

if (!result && error) {
    //Do somethign with the error
}
```

Comment: +1. Yes, you are right. My signatures are wrong. I just realized that myself too.